# Is there a way to tell TypeScript that an array should be a permutation of keys?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I define a type like this:

```
type Keys = "key0" | "key1" | "key2";
```

Now I want to define an array-like type called *Permutation*, which includes every key of type *Keys* **exactly** once.

```
type Permutation = ...;
const example0 = ["key1", "key0", "key2"];         // valid
const example1 = ["key1", "key2"];                 // invalid, "key0" not present
const example2 = ["key1", "key2", "key0", "key0"]; // invalid, "key0" present multiple times
```

Obviously I could define type *Permutation* like so:

```
type Permutation = Keys[];
```

But that definition would not check for my requirements.

Also I don't want to validate the data at runtime, I just want the compiler to tell me that code like in my example is valid or invalid.

An example of a type like this in use could be a table config. Suppose every column has an ID, then this type could be used to define the order of these columns by specifying a permutation of these IDs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you require unique values, why not use `Set<Keys>`?

Comment: @VLAZ Because the Set type does not check if *every* key is present once. Only that there are no duplicate keys.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I misread and thought you wanted non-repeating keys but not necessarily the full set.

Comment: I don't think that's possible without defining all permutations in a type.